# How to use Not Equal Validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hy! how can i use the not equal in validation 
i'm using laravel 5.8. i want to do when i put the (name) something like Admin in input field at the submission of the form it show me error the You can't Use the Name Admin This is all for guest use. when the user is login the he/she can add this name

Answer (score 0):

Laravel offers `notIn` validation rule for this:

```php
Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::notIn(['Admin']), // You can add more values to the array to black list it.
    ],
]);
```

Read [more about this here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-not-in)

Comment: Did it help, @Bilawal?